# javascript pop() method in java

Tags: java, javascript, bukkit

Is there a way that you can use the javascript array.pop() method in java? It would really help if someone finds a way of doing it. I have tried this:

```
 int neighbor = neighbors.get(neighbors.size()-1);
 neighbors.remove(neighbors.size()-1);
```

But it doesn't work i'm getting a error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Your code seems good but list size = 0;

Comment: Maybe you want to use java.util.Stack

Comment: see my answer, it was size 1

Comment: Yes but your comment says Size = 0. Ofcourse as its index is 0 based, trying to access index 1 with a size of 1 is still a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: My opinion it will never happen in java, some info absent

Comment: @user2295443 please post your `neighbor` implemetation

Comment: @MaximShoustin the `java.util.ArrayList` at the Exception seems to tell its the default `ArrayList` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `LinkedList<>` instead of `ArrayList<>`, then you will have access to

```
addFirst()
addLast()
getFirst()
getLast()
removeFirst()
removeLast()
```

Which do the same as push and pop in JS.
It will also require fewer code changes than `Stack<>` since `ArrayList<>` and `LinkedList<>` both implement `List<>`, whereas `Stack<>` is a derivative of `Vector<>`.

You can view the documentation of LinkedList [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).